# Get size of a file and save it to a variable in Windows console?

Tags: windows-server-2008, batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm making a windows batch script, I need to get the specific size of a file so I can Insert that and other values I already got to a database, but I just can't figure out the proper way to do it.

Assuming the name of the file is `c:\test!basename!.zip` (I'm in a for loop here), how can I get the filesize and store it to a variable?

The machine is a Win2008 Server.

**ANSWER**

EliadTech proposed a solution that I've already tried

```
for %I in (test.jpg) do @echo %~zI
```

That worked directly in the command prompt, but failed inside the script.

EliadTech, as we already suspected, thought of checking the escaping, so we got this

```
for %%I in (c:\test\!basename!.zip) do @echo yay %%~zI
```

Works like a charm.

Kinda dumb mistake, but bash has spoiled me beyond repair :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483864/windows-command-for-file-size-only).
I think this is best suited to you:

```
for %I in (test.jpg) do @echo %~zI
```

Comment: I've tried that already, but inside the script, but when doig `for %I in (c:\test\!basename!.zip) do @echo yay %~zI` I got `The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid %~zI`

Comment: I think it's related to the DelayedExpansion - try without it, or replace the "!" with regular "%" just here.

Comment: I suspect it is precisely that (or some weird escaping im not doing). tried both ways, none worked. I'll keep on looking.

Comment: Seriously? it worked OOB for me (though I've tried it straight in the CMD).
Have you added additional "%" before every "%"?
Try running this line separately.

Comment: Yeah, running it directly from the terminal works perfectly, but from the script it fails, lemme try what you say

Comment: You were absolutely right!! this is the line that works `for %%I in (c:\test\!basename!.zip) do @echo yay %%~zI`